# Is there a way to get vpnbook passwords without going to the website?

Tags: vpn

I'm just wondering because it seems that it would be pretty obvious that I'm using a vpn if I go their website to get the new password every week. I'm fairly sure it's not illegal to use a vpn in my country but I just want as much anonymity as possible.

Comment: Any chance you could edit your question to make it clearer what you're asking? Thanks.

Comment: Please see [ask] and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: You cannot hide that you are using a VPN from your network provider. They won't know what you are viewing, but they'll know your VPNing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple! try to access the VPN site from anonymous source. like:

- Public coffee shop with public PC.
- Use Onion routing techs like TOR project.
- Use another VPN provider, there are many free ones.

hope it helps.

Comment: Using the TOR browser sounds right. Can't believe I didn't think of that. Thanks.